# How do I shadow an executable in $PATH?

Tags: path

I have 2 different versions of `pipenv`s in my `$PATH`:

```bsh
$ where pipenv
/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/pipenv #1
/usr/local/bin/pipenv #2
```

and I want to shadow `pipenv` #1 so that #2 can take precedence, while

- keeping `/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin` before `/usr/local/bin` in `$PATH`.
- no `alias pipenv='/usr/local/bin/pipenv'`.
- no running `mv /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/pipenv{,.bak}`,
  or `rm /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/pipenv` (conda will install pipenv in that location again when pipenv is upgraded in the future),
  or uninstalling `pipenv` #1 (it's a dependency of some conda packages),
  or something like that.

How do I do that?

Comment: Remove the executable flag from the local pipenv, but this way you have to execute the local pipenv explicitly with preceded python interpreter. But maybe this will result in unpredictable errors ...

Comment: @ChristophS I think the executable flag will be reset by conda when `pipenv` is upgraded in the future, and that's also why I don't want to `rm` or `mv` it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put another directory, such as `~/bin`, ahead of all the others in your `PATH`. Make a symbolic link to your preferred `pipenv` in that directory. For example:

- Put this line in your `.profile`:

  ```
  PATH=~/bin:$PATH
  ```
- Do this once:

  ```
  mkdir ~/bin
  ln -s /usr/local/bin/pipenv ~/bin
  ```

---

You can also choose which `pipenv` to invoke dynamically if you need to. (For example if your home directory is shared between several machines and you want to have a different preferred `pipenv` on different machines, or if you want a convenient way to select your preferred `pipenv`.) If you want to do that, instead of a symbolic link, create a wrapper script with content like the following and make it executable (`chmod +x ~/bin/pipenv`).

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -x /usr/local/bin/pipenv ]; then
  pipenv=/usr/local/bin/pipenv
elif [ -x /usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/pipenv ]; then
  pipenv=/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/pipenv
else
  pipenv=/usr/bin/pipenv
fi
exec $pipenv "$@"
```

Comment: This is what I need, thank you! I did something like this for other executables before but never really liked it, because I don't know how to manage all those symlinks / wrapper scripts in `~/bin` when I migrate to a new machine. How would you manage them?

Comment: @TeddyC I have two directories under `$HOME` in my path, both under version control: one that contains the same file on every machine, and one for which I have per-machine or per-group-of-machine variants. For a need like yours, I would probably put a wrapper script in the per-machine directory.